# Azure Cosmos DB pagination using azure-documentdb-java

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to understand how to implement pagination using [azure-documentdb-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java). As I see continuation token allows me retrieve only the next page from a query executed earlier.

Is there a way how I can return the concrete page and previous page effortlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Cosmos DB doesn't support (efficient) offset-based pagination. You can use OFFSET LIMIT but it's not efficient. The only efficient pagination mode is token-based. You can get previously fetched pages by memorizing the previous continuation tokens (but if the underlying data has changed, the previous pages will also change).

Comment: If you still stuck with it, refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117304/pagination-in-c-sharp-against-documentdb-without-skip